# How to store operator in variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to store "+" operator in variable.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var m= function(a,b){
return a-b
}
var jj= 10 m 10;
alert(jj)
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: So you want m to act like a + operator?

Comment: Javascript doesn't support operator overloading, however @dystroy's answer is interesting, but nothing more than the same as doing an add() function.

Comment: You didn't put the output that you're expecting from alert(jj), don't leave us guessing...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Avoiding the use of `eval`, I would recommend to use a map of functions :

```
var operators = {
   '+': function(a, b){ return a+b},
   '-': function(a, b){ return a-b}
}
```

Then you can use

```
var key = '+';
var c = operators[key](3, 5);
```

Note that you could also store `operators[key]` in a variable.

Comment: You're a legend :) thumbs up :+1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store an operator in JavaScript like you have requested. You can store a function to a variable and use that instead.

```
var plus = function(a, b) { 
    return a + b;
}
```

Sorry, but JavaScript does not allow this operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

There are ways to use javascript to implement custom versions of operators by playing into the available hooks, but there is no possible way to turn `m` functionally into `+`.

@dystroy has an excellent example of using the available hooks to implement a custom version of operators, but note that it is still just a classic example of using an object to access functions which do some work.